# Should I return a ValueTask or Task in a method which calls an async method

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, azure-cosmosdb

I have a method with the following signature:

```
public async Task<Result> CreateAsync(T entity)
{
    try
    {
        await _c.CreateItemAsync(entity);

        return Result.Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Handle(e); // returns a `Result`
    }
}
```

_c is a `Container` for CosmosDB.

Now, I have another method like this:

```
public Task<Result> CreateUserAsync(User user)
{
    var userEntity = new UserEntity { Id = user.Id, Name = user.Name };
    return CreateAsync(userEntity);
}
```

`Result.Ok()` is a very simple static method of a custom class `Result`:

```
class Result
{
    public static Result Ok() { return new Result(); }.
}
```

So, I have two methods, one being `Task<Result> CreateUserAsync(User user)`, which returns a simple `Task`, without awaiting anything inside it, but the other task that I call at the end `return CreateAsync(userEntity);` awaits stuff inside it.

So to my understanding, `CreateAsync()` should remain as a `Task` return type, because it performs async stuff inside it, but does the method I call it from (that is `CreateUserAsync()`) needs to remain `Task` as well, or can it become a `ValueTask`?

Comment: @MickyD There really isn't too much code, I'll try to edit with more stuff.

Comment: @MickyD Updated, I didn't think it would be relevant to the answer. Sorry.

Comment: @MickyD `Result.Ok()` is a very simple `static` method of a custom class `Result`. `public static Result Ok() { return new Result(); }`.

Comment: There are restrictions on how ValueTask can be used. It's impossible to say whether you can turn Task into ValueTask without knowing how it's used. You can't cache a ValueTask, especially in .NET 5. You can't have multiple continuations. They shouldn't be blocked. Stephen Toub's article on [Async ValueTask Pooling](Async ValueTask Pooling in .NET 5) explains both the optimizations that allow the use of ValueTask in most places *and* the situations where they can't be used

Comment: `ValueTask` is used in a specific scenario, to optimize a case when a generally async operation _could_, under some circumstances, complete synchronously. Is that your case? Can `CreateItemAsync` complete synchronously? Does it itself return a `ValueTask`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, I have edited your answer

Comment: @BorisB. note that the amortised allocation scenario (`IValueTaskSource<T>`) also applies in the fully async case

Comment: @BorisB. No, `CreateItemAsync` can't complete sync. It's an async method, which returns a `Task<T>`.

Comment: You may find these two articles interesting: [Eliding async/await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) and [Understanding the Whys, Whats, and Whens of ValueTask](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/). The concepts of eliding-async-await and Task-vs-ValueTask are orthogonal and mostly unrelated. You can decide for each one independently from the other.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are *functionally* similar, but there are some important differences:

1. if the job completes immediately (synchronously), a `Task<T>` needs to allocate every time (except for some trivial cases around booleans and small integers), where-as a `ValueTask<T>` can avoid the allocation in that case
2. in the genuinely asynchronous case, `ValueTask<T>` *has the potential* to amortise allocations, although this requires special code (`IValueTaskSource<T>` etc)
3. a `Task<T>` can be awaited multiple times, where-as a `ValueTask<T>` should only be awaited once (the behaviour is undefined when awaited more than once, as a side-effect of "2" above)

If this is a high throughput code-path, it may be useful/necessary to think about the allocation overhead of the mechanics, in which case `ValueTask<T>` starts to become very tempting - however, if pre-existing code might already `await` results more than once (violating the 3rd bullet point), this can be problematic. The 1st and 2nd bullet points can have significant impact *if* the async machinery is a significant overhead (after measuring in your scenario).

If this is a low throughput code-path, honestly: do whatever you want. `Task<T>` has the advantange of not needing to even consider the 3rd bullet point, which makes it appealing.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, definitely very helpful. A few things I didn't fully understand. When you say "if a job completes immediately (sync)", that means that it can't be involved with any kind async work (basically a method without the usage of `async/await` keywords in it), is that correct?

Comment: @Axajkamkat it is more complicated than that; something can have multiple `await` and yet still complete synchronously if *all of the `await` were synchronous*; so it comes down to whether there's an actual incomplete async operation in the flow

Comment: Makes sense, in my case since I'm connecting to a database and inserting an item, that would be considered an `async` operation to my understanding. Hence, I should stick with `Task` as my return types.

Comment: @MarcGravell Is there an actual use case (with actual benefits) for #2? If a `ValueTask` method depends on some genuinely-async `Task` method, then it returns something that would always have to be `await`-ed on in order to read the result safely. The only use case I can think of is when the dependent method has a Task signature but you know it's not really async, and/or was written before ValueTask existed.